# Repeating tag with Jaxb

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, xsd

As Im beginner with xsd and jaxb, I'm quite stuck on this one, even though looked up on the net, nothing similar:

I want to facilitate in my program writing xsd using jaxb so representing an accordion with my class :

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "div")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "h3", "div" })
public class Accordion {

String id;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

@XmlAttribute
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

String h3;

public String getH3() {
    return h3;
}

@XmlElement
public void setH3(String h3) {
    this.h3 = h3;
}

String div;

public String getDiv() {
    return div;
}

@XmlElement
public void setDiv(String div) {
    this.div = div;
}}
```

While marshaling an object : the result is as follows :

```
<div id="title 25">
    <h3>hi1</h3>
    <div>div content</div>
</div>
```

Now the problem is that I want h3 and div repeated inside div, something like this :

```
<div id="title 25">
    <h3>hi1</h3>
    <div>div content</div>
    <h3>hi2</h3>
    <div>div content 2</div>
    ...
</div>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the XML you are looking for, you just need to change your model to something like the following and leverage `@XmlElementRefs`/`@XmlElementRef`.

```
@XmlElementRefs({
    @XmlElementRef(name="h3", type=JAXBElement.class),
    @XmlElementRef(name="div", type=JAXBElement.class)
})
public List<JAXBElement<String>> getH3AndDiv() {
    return h3AndDiv;
}
```

**Full Example**

- [require either one element or the other in JAXB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22502171/require-either-one-element-or-the-other-in-jaxb/22502785#22502785)

Comment: Thanks for answering, I guess your solution is limited to choosing only one element at a time, whereas I would like to have h3 followed by div, and repeat as long as we want, like h3 then div then h3 then div, etc.

Comment: @ZakariaBouazza - I'm not sure what you mean.  In this cause the instance of `JAXBElement` holds the element name and the value.  Then you can arrange how you want them to appear based on the order in which they occur in the list.

Comment: It finally works, I proceeded with reverse engineering, by creating classes from an xsd containing sequence file, and got eh object factory, Thanks a lot!